# Cannot build UE4 project as Android package because UPL code can't find package

Tags: android, gson, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to package an android library into my Plugin. I was successful with one import but when I try to leverage Google's GSON one I get the following error:

```
LogPlayLevel: Error:   Z:\app\src\main\java\com\epicgames\ue4\GameActivity.java:209: error: package com.google.code.gson does not exist
LogPlayLevel:             import com.google.code.gson.Gson;
LogPlayLevel:                                        ^
LogPlayLevel: Error:   Z:\app\src\main\java\com\epicgames\ue4\GameActivity.java:210: error: package com.google.code.gson does not exist
LogPlayLevel:             import com.google.code.gson.JsonElement;
LogPlayLevel:                                        ^
LogPlayLevel: Error:   Z:\app\src\main\java\com\epicgames\ue4\GameActivity.java:520: error: cannot find symbol
LogPlayLevel:       private Gson gson = new Gson();
LogPlayLevel:               ^
LogPlayLevel:     symbol:   class Gson
LogPlayLevel:     location: class GameActivity
LogPlayLevel:   3 errors
```

I've tested the code in an Android Studio and it works fine

```
    <AARImports>
        <insertValue value="com.google.code.gson,gson,2.8.2" />
        <insertNewline/>
    </AARImports>
```

I've put that in place as well. No errors at all regarding fetching the package, only the errors shown at the top.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste issue. Just need to change `import com.google.code.gson.Gson` (and the JsonElement line) to `import com.google.gson.Gson`. Derp!